# Painfully slow local development and MS-SQL connection

Tags: networking, vpn, security, sql-server, web-development

I know some may suggest that this question needs to be asked on StackOverFlow, but I do not believe this is not a Dev issue and probably an IT/Security thing. I have posted this on ServerFault as well.

I am the newest developer in a company and I work remotely. I have received a top notch fast development laptop which is the same as everyone else.
This Laptop is connected to a USB-C to Lan adapter, then to a network switch, then to my router (all with Lan connection).

I use a VPN to connect to databases and whatnot. Among all developers, My environment has the slowest (by like 10~20X) performance. So every time I make a code change and recompile my code I have to wait 12~15min for things to load!

I have profiled my code and have noticed that SQL queries take painfully long time to execute.
A query that takes 70~90s to run on my machine through SSMS (or VisualStudio), takes less than 2s on other developers machines. (One of the developers lives in the same town as me and uses the same internet provider)

Some of the C# operations that take less than a ms to run on other laptops, take like 70ms~150ms on my machine.

Another developer and me pinged the same database server and we had comparable statistics, (delay, both zero packet loss, etc., similar internet speed after connecting to VPN) but still my queries took much longer to execute! The query is also a simple
 `Select top(10000) ID from someTable`

- I have disabled my Antivirus (again same thing on everyone's PC) and
  no luck!
- I have connected the laptop (via USB-C -> LAN hub) to my router (eliminating the switch), still no luck.
- I have modified my hosts file to point localhost to 127.0.0.1 to make sure these calls are not going outside and still no luck.
- I have pointed my Dev to other databases and no luck! everything still super slow.
- I have disconnected my Lan and used WIFI to connect to my router, still no luck!
- I have asked IT and they don't have a clue! I have done a whole bunch of other tests but I really doubt if it is something local!
- during run time I have given 'Realtime' priority to all Visual Studio/IIS/SSMS processes and still no luck.

What are the other things that I can ask our It to check and what are the other local settings/stuff that I can check?
Whatever it is, to me it seems that it knows what packets are going where and what their content is and can scan/delay them selectively!

I am going to disable Windows Firewall and see but I really doubt that it is the culprit.

Comment: What's the timing when booting in Safe mode with Networking?

Comment: @harrymc  Thanks! I will measure and give you an update! Just out of curiosity, what can we get out of it?

Comment: In Safe mode only Microsoft's software is allowed. This narrows the field.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling TCP/IP connections to the local dev server could resolve this issue.

1. Start -> Run -> mmc
2. File -> Add/Remove Snap-in...
3. SQL Server Configuration Manager -> [OK]
4. SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER -> TCP/IP=Enabled
5. Restart server.